# 1071 Specified key was too long; max key length is 767 bytes

Tags: mysql, sql, utf-8

На локальном сервере возникает такая ошибка при попытке сменить кодировку и сопоставление таблицы на `utf8mb4`, а на удаленном - нет. Причину ошибки я знаю, мне интересно ,почему поведение различается. Локальный mysql - 5.5.45, удаленный - 5.5.55.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Судя по [ответам на похожий вопрос в английской версии SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1814532/1071-specified-key-was-too-long-max-key-length-is-767-bytes) в INNODB движке (вплоть до версии MySQL 5.5.14) существуют следующие ограничения на длину поля с уникальным ключем:

- `INNODB utf8 VARCHAR(255)`
- `INNODB utf8mb4 VARCHAR(191)`

**сравните [sysvar_innodb_large_prefix](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/innodb-parameters.html#sysvar_innodb_large_prefix) параметр в обеих БД**

> Enable this option to allow index key prefixes longer than 767 bytes
>   (up to 3072 bytes), for InnoDB tables that use DYNAMIC or COMPRESSED
>   row format. (Creating such tables also requires the option values
>   innodb_file_format=barracuda and innodb_file_per_table=true.) See
>   Section 14.11.8, “Limits on InnoDB Tables” for maximums associated
>   with index key prefixes under various settings.
>
> For tables that use REDUNDANT or COMPACT row format, this option does
>   not affect the permitted index key prefix length. When this setting is
>   enabled, attempting to create an index prefix with a key length
>   greater than 3072 for a REDUNDANT or COMPACT table causes an
>   ER_INDEX_COLUMN_TOO_LONG error.

Comment: да, различается - innodb_large_prefix на локальной БД ON, на удаленной - OFF. Но ведь в этом случае ошибка должна проявляться на удаленной, разве нет? И чем тогда чревато то, что я на удаленной БД применяю ALTER TABLE без предварительной подготовки таких полей?

Comment: @Mik, вы уверены? По идее должно быть наоборот... А данные одинаковые в обеих БД? Я сейчас проверить не смогу...

Comment: Да, совершенно уверен. На всех БД, где смена кодировки прошла без ошибки, innodb_large_prefix=OFF.

Comment: Как выяснилось, на локалхосте не работает даже после `set global innodb_large_prefix = 'OFF'`

Comment: @Mik, укажите скрипт для создания данного столбца: `CREATE TABLE ...`

Comment: `Name` VARCHAR(255) NULL DEFAULT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_bin'

Comment: @Mik, попробуйте уменьшить до `VARCHAR(191)`. Вначале стоит проверить максимальную длину строки в этом столбце....

Comment: Это работает, проверял, но таких полей достаточно много в нескольких БД, и в некоторых длина наверняка выйдет за 191. Хотелось бы обойтись без обрезки длины.

Comment: тогда включайте `innodb_large_prefix = ON` и убедитесь, что все условия (указаны в ответе) выполнены

Comment: Да, видимо, так и сделаю. А суть оказалась в другом: на обоих серверах по полю был создан уникальный индекс, но на удаленном сервере поле имеет тип `INT(11)`, чего я, к сожалению, не увидел сразу. Вот поэтому там изменения сработали, а на локальном - нет.

Comment: Я ответил на ваш изначальный вопрос? ;-)

Comment: Да, спасибо, вы мне очень помогли!